# In Excel, can I sum a dynamic, yet specific range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm very new to Excel, and as a small project I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that allows me to input hours I've worked into a time-sheet, have Excel total the hours for me, then add the wages I've earned into a total that is my Bank Balance on Payday.

So, I've essentially gotten every piece of that down so far, save for the very tricky part of "On a Payday, add the total of the past 14 days to my Bank Balance."

I have a logical check to tell Excel when it IS Payday, I know what I need to do, I just don't know how to do it OR if it is even possible. :(

My timesheet looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YufD.png

What I essentially want to do is this:

if payday:

```
match today's date with the end date of a week                                           -- if Today is a payday, it will 
take the row that has that date, and the row above it. this is the range I want.         -- match up with the end date 
total all hours from within the range                                                    -- of a week listed.
multiply the total by 10.50
add that total to the Bank Balance
```

I'm sorry about everything being a mess and requesting such a strange, complicated answer :(

I appreciate anyone's help if they are able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INT(M2),J:J,0)),SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(INT(M2),J:J,0)-1):INDEX(H:H,MATCH(INT(M2),J:J,0))),0)
```

Where M2 has the formula: `=TODAY()` (I hard coded the date to make sure it works)

[image]

Then it is just a matter of multiplying the returned value by 10.5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something we could do with an `OFFSET` formula. The `OFFSET` function takes a start cell, then offsets a certain number of rows and columns, and returns a range of a certain size. In this case, we'd use something like this:
`=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH($S7,$J$2:$J$37,0),0,1,7))`

The `OFFSET` function uses B1 as an anchor point. The `MATCH` function looks down column J to see where it finds a match for the date we're currently interested in, and returns a number indicating where it finds that value. We feed that number back to the `OFFSET`, so the formula knows to look that many rows below its anchor point. We then use a hard-coded 0, so the `OFFSET` stays looking in column B, and return a range of cells that is 1 row in height and 7 columns wide. That range is passed to the SUM, and the SUM adds up the numbers.